# Save to file - Authentication bearer code

Tags: python, json

```
def codeGET(www, code):

        r = requests.get(www)
        #token=r.headers.get('Authorization: bearer')
        #token=r.headers.get('Authorization')
        token=r.headers.get('bearer')

        response=requests.get(www,
                      headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                               'Authorization': 'bearer {}'.format(token)})
        if not response.status_code == code:
            file = open("file", 'a')
            file.write("Method: " + response.request.method)
            file.write("Token: " + str(token) + "\n")
            file.close()
```

When I send without bearer I get code - 403 (I need 200). I need bearer token. I tried create code 3 times:

```
        token=r.headers.get('Authorization: bearer')
        token=r.headers.get('Authorization')
        token=r.headers.get('bearer')
```

but every single time I had : None
Save to file:
Token: None

Of course, when I send bearer = None I get code 401

How I can change my code? Where is problem, that I get None, but no bearer code.?

Comment: If the implementation is strict it might refuse the lowercase `bearer`. The header should be `Authorization: Bearer token`.

Answer (score 0):

You need use : token=r.headers.get('authorization: bearer') - only lowercase

But maybe is different solution.